# .inputrc, TAB and CTRL-i

Tags: terminal, putty, readline, inputrc

Apparently, when we hit <kbd>TAB</kbd> in Terminal, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> is send instead, so we cannot have different bindings for these keypresses in our .inputrc:

```
"\C-i": forward-char
TAB: complete
```

This makes TAB move the cursor one character forward instead of showing the completion menu. Is there any way to make the above configuration work?

I am using Putty under Windows.

Comment: For the record, the tab key normally sends the ASCII Control-I character. Do you have reason to believe there’s a way to differentiate which key was pressed? (There may in fact be a way to configure the terminal to send an escape sequence for one or both of the keys in order to allow differentiation. Have you confirmed that .inputrc’s “TAB” maps to an escape sequence, or is it always just an alias for Control-I?)